# Como puedo reiniciar un script de python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

Hola me preguntaba como puedo reiniciar mi script de Python explico, después de ejecutar cierta función te preguntara si quieres quedar en la aplicación o no si no es simplemente quit() pero no se que poner en el else

```
# EXIT OR STAY #
def EORS():
    print("Want to follow on RIFT Console")
Condition = input("[Y] [N]")

if Condition != "Y":
    quit()
else:
    #Que va aquí para REINICIAR el SCRIPT desde el PRINCIPIO#
```

UTILIZO PYTHON 3.9.6

Comment: Bienvenido ANONIMO,  mas allá de la respuesta, quería preguntar.... ¿sabes usar sentencias repetitivas(while)? o recursividad??. ambos conceptos te pueden ayudar a dar solución a tu problema. Podrimos darte una solución pero debido a que son conceptos fundamentales en la programación seria bueno que lo implementes conforme los vayas aprendiendo.

Comment: en Python no pero si en lua aparte paso mucho desde que programaba en lua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te mencione en los comentarios , tienes estas dos formas para solucionar tu problema:

**Usar WHILE:**

Encierra el contenido de la función dentro de un while con una afirmación para siempre iterar su contenido.

```
# EXIT OR STAY #
def EORS():
    while True:
        print("Want to follow on RIFT Console")
        Condition = input("[Y] [N]")
        if Condition != "Y":
            quit()
        else:
            pass
```

o

**Usar RECURSIVIDAD y llamar a la misma función:**

```
# EXIT OR STAY #
def EORS():
    print("Want to follow on RIFT Console")
    Condition = input("[Y] [N]")
    if Condition != "Y":
        quit()
    else:
        EORS()
```

Te reitero como en el comentario, estos dos conceptos son fundamentales, y serán parte de tu día a día como programador, así que mas allá de darle una solución a tu código estúdialo en esencia para que no importe el lenguaje donde lo uses y siempre sepas utilizarlo, por favor toma ese consejo.

Comment: Ok Gracias por el tip

Comment: Si la pregunta es valida y soluciona tu problema, por favor dale como aceptada para que cuando alguien tenga la misma duda pueda encontrarla fácilmente.

Comment: Si, pero a lo que me referia es que te pregunta de volver al inicio de la app, que te devuelva al en este caso primer input

Comment: A que te refieres con "el primer input"? en tu código solo veo uno. Por favor se mas claro en tus preguntas y comentarios, recuerda que hay toda una comunidad.

Comment: me refiero a mi programa empieza con un input y luego sigue tiene varias funciones crear ficheros leerlos etc y cada vez que se ejecute una funcion quiero que te pregunte si cerrar el programa o volver al principio por eso el codigo de la pregunta

Comment: Probaste el código que te proporcione? xq me parece que no lo hiciste.  Entiendes que el código que te proporcioné vuelve al principio si tu lo quisieras? todo va depender de como lo implementes. Te repito, trata de aprender esos 2 conceptos.

Comment: Te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por [ask], te ayudara a mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas